# Some of my pages look messed up in IE

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have been building this site and I am getting close to finishing.  So I decided to check it in IE and Firefox (I use Chrome) The site looks great in Chrome and FireFox but some of the pages are messed up in Internet Explorer!

What would cause this?? I know I've heard people say IE is always glitchy but most people use IE and I am getting paid to make a site for the masses.

Some one Please Help!!

here is the test link:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/index.html

Comment: upon further inspection Fire Fox is glitchy too.  The scroll bars won't work and the "Menus" pages some how the whole div gets moved down???

Comment: The site renders ok, but the scrollbar on the menus page doesn't work for me in FF8.

Comment: Tip: Install `IE9` there is web developer tools by which you can see what designing faults in your website as well as you can check in IE7,8 with the help of that tool

Comment: anyways your website looking perfect in `IE9`. can u specify which pages are not coming with proper design

Comment: @Commentors: The OP does state the site is still in-development. I suspect that the menu pages haven't been finished yet, as evidenced by the fact they all have the same text. :D So I would assume the scrollbars haven't been implemented yet.

Comment: The scroll bar on the menus prolly don't work because I don't have enough content in them.

The problem areas for me are "Event Center" "About Us" and some others, a thin black line appears at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a Doctype. IE renders the site in Quirks mode due to no DOCTYPE declaration. 
Rest everything seems ok when viewed in IE 7,8,9 mode

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

Comment: This worked... for the most part. For some reason its bumping down the "menus pages"... any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Didn't get this: "Bumping down the menu pages" ? Please elaborate or even better if you could show screenshots depicting differences

Answer (score 3):

Various browsers have various rendering engines and rules.  This can cause the same markup to be rendered differently in different browsers.

I would recommend specifying a DOCTYPE as it looks like you've not added one, this will prevent IE rendering in quirks mode.

Other guidelines are to use clean semantic markup and style using CSS only.

And regularly check your site in other browsers!

Answer (score 1):

Adding this:

```
<!doctype html>
```

To the top of your document will help IE render in the best possible document mode. Additionally, you can add this meta tag to your `head`  section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

This will make IE7, 8, and 9 render the site in the most modern rendering engine it has available.

IE6 is a different story altogether, if you want to support it fully be prepared for many hours of tweaking :D. If you want to dive even deeper I can recommend having a look at these two sites as well:

- http://www.modernizr.com/
- http://html5reset.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the link in IE8 and I can't see any obvious 'mess ups'. If you're designing for earlier versions of IE, then you need to remember that not all CSS properties work in IE, or not in the same way as other browsers.

[This link](http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/index.html) gives a detailed list of the supported CSS functions for each version of IE.

It is also worth taking a look at [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) when designing your websites.

Obviously, without more detail from you, it is very hard to give a specific answer (take a look at the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for future questions) but you should be able to go on in the right direction now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need to use different `stylesheets` for those browsers which have problems.

Please read this article about [How to Use Different CSS Style Sheets For Different Browsers](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml)

Hope this help